# Change byte in Int64

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Recently I asked the question: [Replace byte in a int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161285/replace-byte-in-a-int)

and that shows how to replace a byte on an integer. **I need to do the same thing with Int64 too**. Apparently I am to bad at this lol. I do not know why replacing int to Int64 does not make it work. In other words I modified the solutions on the last question to:

```
static Int64 ReplaceByte1( int index , Int64 value , byte replaceByte )
{
    return ( value & ~( 0xFF << ( index * 8 ) ) ) | ( replaceByte << ( index * 8 ) );
}

static Int64 ReplaceByte2( int index , Int64 value , byte replaceByte )
{
    // how many bits you should shift replaceByte to bring it "in position"
    var shiftBits = 8 * index;

    // bitwise AND this with value to clear the bits that should become replaceByte
    Int64 mask = ~( 0xff << shiftBits );

    // clear those bits and then set them to whatever replaceByte is
    return value & mask | ( replaceByte << shiftBits );
}
```

that does not work when using large values. For example calling the method as:

```
        // returns 12345678848  where it should return 3755744309
        var test1 = ReplaceByte1( 4 , 12345678901 , 0 );

        // returns 12345678848  where it should return 3755744309
        var test2 = ReplaceByte2( 4 , 12345678901 , 0 );
```

how can I make it work with Int64 too? what am I doing wrong? The only method that works is the last one the slowest one.

### Edit

**I already made the replacements and I still get different results**. Why? take a look:

```
    // method that words
    static Int64 SlowReplace ( int index , Int64 value , byte replaceByte )
    {
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( value );
        bytes[ index ] = replaceByte;

        return BitConverter.ToInt64( bytes , 0 );
    }

    static Int64 ReplaceByte1 ( int index , Int64 value , byte replaceByte )
    {
        return ( value & ~( (long)0xFF << ( index * 8 ) ) ) | ( replaceByte << ( index * 8 ) );
    }

    static Int64 ReplaceByte2 ( int index , Int64 value , byte replaceByte )
    {
        // how many bits you should shift replaceByte to bring it "in position"
        var shiftBits = 8 * index;

        // bitwise AND this with value to clear the bits that should become replaceByte
        Int64 mask = ~( ( Int64 )0xff << shiftBits );

        // clear those bits and then set them to whatever replaceByte is
        return value & mask | ( replaceByte << shiftBits );
    }        

    static void Main ( string[ ] args )
    {
        var a = SlowReplace( 4 , 12345678901 , 255 ); //  1098972404789 corect
        var b = ReplaceByte1( 4 , 12345678901 , 255 ); // 3755744511 incorrect
        var c = ReplaceByte2( 4 , 12345678901 , 255 ); // 3755744511 incorrect            

        Console.Read( );            
    }
```

Comment: Convert to byte array. Modify index. Convert array to long. System.BitConverter will help

Comment: Yeah I know I have that solution on the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161285/replace-byte-in-a-int  But note how slow it is compared to the other approaches on the results.

Answer (score 2):

The problem now relies in the `replaceByte << shiftBits` expression.
Refer to the `<< Operator` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/a1sway8w%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx).

The documentation states that if the first operand is a 32-bit quantity (which in this case it is, because an implicit cast is performed on the `byte` variable), the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of the second operand. In this case, because `shiftBits` equals 32 = 2^5, which in binary representation is 100000, the low-order five bits are 00000.

Aside from an explicit cast (`(long)0xFF`) you can also suffix constants with an `l` or an `L` to mark them as `long` / `Int64` (or `ul` / `UL` for `ulong` / `UInt64`), but `0xFFL` can be considered less aesthetic/readable by some. For the `replaceByte << shiftBits` situation an explicit cast is required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the constant `0xff` to `long`:

```
Int64 mask = ~( (Int64)0xff << shiftBits );
```

If you don't do this and `index` is greater than 3 then `mask` will have the wrong value because the literal `0xff` is an `int` and there is also [this rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx):

> If the first operand is an int or uint (32-bit quantity), the shift
>   count is given by the low-order five bits of the second operand. That
>   is, the actual shift count is 0 to 31 bits.

Since in this case the shift count is a power of two and greater than 31 its low-order five bits will all be zero, which will result in no shift at all (as if `shiftBits == 0`). So `mask` will have the wrong value and it will clear the wrong bits out of `value`, producing a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `0xFF << ( index * 8 )` with `(long)0xFF << ( index * 8 )`